# Is there a way to configure an AEM server plugin on Intellij that will push changes to author

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, development-environment, aem

Currently I use `Eclipse` to develop my `AEM application`. I do that because `Eclipse` has a plugin that pushes any code changes to the `AEM Author instance` running in the background.

Is there such a solution for `Intellij`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IntelliVault](https://github.com/shsteimer/IntelliVault) will allow you to upload content (including Sightly, JSP, clientlib resources, etc.) to your AEM instance from your IDE. It's very similar to the [VaultClipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vaultclipse) plugin for Eclipse.

Both of them use [FileVault (VLT)](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html) behind the scenes.